# Android NotificationListenerService: how to know if user clicked on the notification (opening the related app) or simply deleted it

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I'm working with notifications generated by every app (not only mine) on my Android device (android 5.1.1).
By extending NotificationListenerService I'm able to know when a push notification is posted (overriding the "onNotificationPosted" method) and when a notification is removed (overriding the "onNotificationRemoved" method).

The problem is that I would like to know how the notification was removed:
a) by clicking it (so opening the app)
or
b) by swyping it (so it is only removed)
?

Is it possible to know it?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is to get the list of all running processes!
So, in the onNotificationRemoved method we can:
  1. obtain the list of running processes using the [Android Processes](https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidProcesses) library
  2. compare each process name with the packageName
  3. if the comparison return a true value, we check if the process is in foreground

```
public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
    try {
        List<AndroidAppProcess> processes = ProcessManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (processes != null) {
            for (AndroidAppProcess process : processes) {
                String processName = process.name;
                if (processName.equals(packageName)) {
                    if (process.foreground ==true)
                    {
                        //user clicked on notification
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //user swipe notification
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String error = e.toString();
    }
}
```